# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = false always in Nginx Enviroment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nginx, load-balancing

There is a problem I happened, I use nginx to implement load balancing. I use the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` + distributed Redis cache to tell server the user is logged in.

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && RedisSession.IsExistKey("Username"))
       //HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"] == null
    {
       base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

I found that the redis cache is okay, but `httpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`
is true in one of the sites. On the other site it always returns false.

For example: I mapped two IIS website using different port using nginx, when I refresh the test page, it will give me different answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you Login the user into your application? In order for HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated to be true you have to add the user to the IdentityStore at some point. Have a look here for an example of how this is done in Mvc https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset#require

Comment: @Alex I've done it ,but it can only login in one website,the other's status is False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in a load balanced environment you should share your website Session across both sites.

This way both IIS instances will be aware of the user. So you have to use an 'out of process' cache implementation for your websites.

This is a [walkthrough](http://deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/memcached-for-c----a-walkthrough/%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B62) of one such solution using [Memcached](https://memcached.org/).

Comment: I solved the problem,just add Machine key across the different web server.